# Java Regex any numbers separated by a character and terminated with a number

Tags: java, regex

I need to have a pattern to match the following strings

```
564 A 456
10 O 94 A 465 
234 A 654 O 1 
3 A 5697 O 68998 A 89789 A 665 
2 A 5646 A 123 A 123 
231 O 645 O 4565 O 564
```

Translation would...

Any number with any length (1 to *)

Followed by a space

Followed by any number with any length (1 to *)

Follwed by **A** or **B**

For example the following test would **not** be valid

```
A 465 //not begin with a number
564 AO 5645 //only A or O should appear Not both!
4564 A //not end in number
987 T 213 //invalid character T
1456 456 A 56 //invalid whitespace in first number
987 O 321654 987 //invalid whitespace in last number
12 A 456 O 132 A //not end in a number
```

At this moment i have this pattern  `\d+\s((A|O)\s\d+)*`

But does not recognize all my valid string

Comment: Is string like `"123"` valid (it doesn't have letter and number after it)?

Comment: Your input doesn't match you description: number space number (A or B).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you want to accept number (`\d+` - one or more digits) which can be followed by one or more of
`(A or O) number`.

In that case your regex can look like `\d+(\s[AO]\s\d+)+`
but since `\` is special in String its literal needs to be written as `"\\d+(\\s[AO]\\s\\d+)+"`.

BTW, some of your lines in your example of valid strings ends with space so either trim this data before validation, or add `\s?` at the end of regex to also include this space.

Comment: Thanks!! this pattern match all my tests.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to include the space into the parenthesis, like this:

```
\d+(\s(A|O)\s\d+)*
```

And that should work like a charm!